# Is this possible in API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I've been asked to look into an AWS setup for my organisation but this isn't my area of experience so it's a bit of a challenge.  After doing some research, I'm hoping that API Gateway will work for us and I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me if I'm along the right lines.
The plan is:

1. We create a VPC with several private subnets.  The EC2 instances in the subnets will be hosting browser based applications like Apache Guacamole, Splunk etc.
2. We attach to the VPC an API Gateway with a REST API which will allow users access to only the applications on 'their' subnet
3. Users follow a link to the API Gateway from an external API which will provide Oauth2 credentials.
4. The API Gateway REST API verifies their credentials and serves them with a page with links to the private IP addresses for the services in 'their' subnet only.  They can then click on the links and open the Splunk, Guacamole browser pages etc.

I've also looked at Client VPN as a possible solution but my organisation wants users to be able to connect directly to the individual subnets from an existing API without having to download any other tools (this is due to differing levels of expertise of users and the need to work remotely).  If there is a better solution which would provide the same workflow then I'd be happy to implement that instead.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You should look at ALB. It provides authentication with Cognito or any identity provider compatible with OpenID Connect. It could be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like it could work in theory. My main concern would be if Apache Guacomole, or any of the other services you are trying to expose, requires long lived HTTP connections. API Gateway has a hard requirement that all requests must take no longer than 29 seconds.

I would suggest also looking into exposing these services via a public Application Load Balancer, instead of API Gateway, which has [OIDC authentication support](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/built-in-authentication-in-alb/). You'll need to look at the requirements of the specific services you are trying to expose to evaluate if API Gateway or ALB would be a better fit.

---

I would personally go about this by configuring each of these environments using an Infrastructure as Code, in such a way that you can create a new client environment by simply running your IaC tool with a few parameters like the client ID and the domain name or subdomain you want to use. I would actually spin each up in their own VPC since it sounds like you want each client's environment to be isolated from the others.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn’t realise the Gateway has a time limit and we’ll definitely need longer than that.  The amount of vpc’s we would need would be over the aws limit but the application load balancer sounds promising.

Comment: The VPC limit is a soft limit that can be increased by submitting a ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about VPC limits also.  All of these answers have been really helpful